# How to get Maven project BaseDir() from java Code

Tags: java, maven-2

How to get Maven project basedir() from my Java code?

Comment: You should probably back up a step and explain what you're trying to do. This question is pretty vague and sounds like sounds like you're trying to do something the wrong way.

Comment: In java 8 you can use this code: `Paths.get("").toFile().getAbsolutePath()` or `FileSystems.getDefault()`

Comment: I want to get basedir from my Java code in unit test(src/test/java) to parse my config(src/main/resources/config/*.xml). It it easy to use.  Paths.get("").toFile().getAbsolutePath() @xbmono

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation), there's a maven property `${project.basedir}`

If you include a properties file in your resources, which has the `${project.basedir}` placeholder, and [enable filtering for the resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), you will find that there's a build time substitution of the basedir into the properties file. You can then load this using a `Properties` instance in code.

in /src/main/resources, create a file called project.properties, containing

```
my.basedir=${project.basedir}
```

Then, in the POM, enable filtering for /src/main/resources, as outlined in the maven resources filtering documentation linked above.

Then, in code, at runtime, load the properties file into a `Properties` instance

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("project.properties"));
String myBasedir = props.get("my.basedir");
```

An alternative would be to process some source files and do substitution in there by hooking into the `process-sources` phase, but that's not likely to be easy to explain.

Comment: I used ${basedir} property in my pom and it works fine but How can I get that in my Java code?

Comment: By following the instructions above. I'll try to make the path a little clearer

Comment: @ptomli when I write ${project.version} into my pom file I can retrieve its value however when I write it into a properties file I can not. I am developing a custom maven plugin, what should I do?

Comment: @kamaci That would depend on a lot of things, but the first I'd look at is to check that the resources plugin is filtering the properties file. Also, don't ask questions in comments, create a new question, you'll get a far better response.

Comment: @kamaci According to [**Defining Parameters Within a Mojo**](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Defining_Parameters_Within_a_Mojo): "_The `defaultValue` ...  can include expressions which reference the project_" you can use `@Parameter(defaultValue="${[project.]basedir}") private String baseDir;`. [`@Parameter(defaultValue="${session}") private String session; session.getExecutionRootDirectory()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html) should work, too.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you want this when run from 'exec:exec' or 'test'.  If that's the case, you can get it via

```
System.getProperties().get("basedir")
```

Comment: This doesn't work. What it does work is telling the maven-exec-plugin to pass a system property (name it as you wish) using Maven's ${project.basedir}. something like this:
<systemProperties>
 <systemProperty>
  <key>basedir</key>
  <value>${project.basedir}</value>
 </systemProperty>
</systemProperties>

Comment: This solution works for me on maven 3.0.3, though obviously it will take more than just that to work from maven *and* in the IDE.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this approach is not recommended by maven, as it can be seen here: https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/common-bugs.html

Comment: @DTK it is a 10-year-old answer... a lot has changed.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, because maven is used for building, and doesn't "exist" after the build.

If you need that during the build (for example via the exec plugin), then it is either accessible as a system propery or you can pass it as argument to the executed program.

Comment: I found this code at Maven site   file = new File( project.getBasedir(), file ); but I don't know how to get this project object http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/common-bugs.html#Resolving_Relative_Paths

Comment: @FerasOdeh: Are you developing a plugin? If not, that site isn't going to help you.

Comment: You're talking about writing a maven plugin? If this is true then you'll have access to the `project` via the maven plugin API.

Comment: @Feras Odeh - what is your usecase - why do you need that?

Comment: @FerasOdeh, see here https://www.baeldung.com/maven-plugin#2-creating-the-mojo-class

To have access to the project information, we have to add a MavenProject as a parameter:

`@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
MavenProject project;`