# Get the target directory path in Maven (Java)

Tags: java, maven

In a Maven project I want write some test results into a file in target directory of the project. Whenever, I get the project directory, it is actually getting the IntelliJ project directory instead of actual Maven directory.

Comment: Theres a somewhat sound solution for this problem here worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808664/how-to-get-maven-project-basedir-from-java-code - in short you can get the maven  project base directory and that may be what you are looking for, hope it works out if not let me know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution for this. Here is how I am implementing. I have my own class CSVReader which uses CSVReader library. I am writing my results in results.csv file under target directory.

```
URL location = CSVReader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String path = location.getFile().replace("classes/","") + "results.csv";
```

In the above code I am getting the target directory path and removing the classes/ by string replace method and appending my desired file name. Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 13):

You could also use `java.nio.file.Paths`:

```
URL url = Paths.get("target", "results.csv").toUri().toURL();
```

Answer (score 5):

I used the answer above with a slight modification (I can't add comments).
Since tests are placed into the 'test' folder, their classes will reside in 'target/test-classes' (so replacing 'classes' might not give you the expected result). Instead, I used the following:

```
File targetClassesDir = new File(ExportDataTest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
File targetDir = targetClassesDir.getParentFile();
```

Comment: Why this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()   would give you the path with a slash appended to the front?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the classloaders root resource path for retrieving projects build directory with following single line:

```
Path targetPath = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/").toURI()).getParent();
```

The root resource path points to `test-classes` and it's parent is the desired path regardless of running the test via maven surefire or a JUnit runner of the IDE like Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The following solutions work for me:

```
URL location = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
String path = location.getFile().replace("/test-classes/","").replace("/classes/","");
```

or

```
Path targetPath = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/").toURI()).getParent();
String path = targetPath.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the location of the class, where you are running your logic in order to get the location of the target path. I use the following code in order to achieve that:

```
URL target = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org/mycomp/home/model").toURI().toURL();
```